# Tweepy For Loop For IDs Extract, Something Not Right

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, twitter, tweepy

I have the following code to `extract ids` out of a series of `usernames` and append to a pandas dataframe called `new_followers_df`:

```
twitter_handles = ["x", "y"]    

## Import New Twitter Followers

new_follower_ids = []
handles = []

for user in twitter_handles:

    while True:

        try:

            for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name= user).pages():
                new_follower_ids.extend(page)
                for ids in page:
                    handles.append(user)
        except tweepy.TweepError:
            time.sleep(60 * 15)
            continue

        except StopIteration:
            pass
        break

new_followers_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Handles": handles,
    "Follower_ID": new_follower_ids})
```

If `user x` had `75,000 users` and `user y` another `75,000` I calculated it should take me `30 minutes` to scrape all of `user X and Y's followers`.

This due to the fact that the API has a limit of `5000 ids per Cursor`, `15 calls per session`, and a `15 minute wait in between`.

However, for some reason, the script is taking much longer to complete. Any idea if there's something wrong in my for loop? Could it be possile that is has something to do with : `StopIteration`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tweepy
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

new_followers_df = pd.DataFrame()

def download_followers(user, api):
    all_followers = []
    try:
        for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=user).pages():
            all_followers.extend(map(str, page))
        return all_followers
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        print('Could not access user {}. Skipping...'.format(user))

# Include your keys below:
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

# Set up tweepy API, with handling of rate limits
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
main_api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

# List of usernames to get followers for
lookup_users = ['x',
 'y',
 'z',
 'a',
 'b']

for username in lookup_users:
    user_followers = download_followers(username, main_api)
    if user_followers:
        new_followers = pd.DataFrame({
            "Handles": username,
            "Follower_ID": user_followers,
            "Start_Date": datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d')})

        new_followers_df = new_followers_df.append(new_followers)


        print('Finished outputting: {} at {}'.format(username, datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things that might be going on.

1. If you've been testing your program, you've probably user some of those calls in your 15 minute window for testing.
2. `pandas` will probably take some time to append 150,000 values to a Dataframe.
3. Not entirely sure about this, but it's possible your use of `page` twice (`extend(page)` then `for ids in page`) is using up two calls if the `page` is a generator. This is a bit of a guess, and I might be entirely wrong.

You can, however, recode this to work a little more elegantly and hopefully reduce the slow times you're getting.

First of all, you don't have to handle rate limits yourself. `tweepy` can do this when you initialise your API. Presumably at some point in your code you have the line:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

If we change this to:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
```

`tweepy` will wait when you hit rate limits, and a message will be printed to tell you that it is waiting.

Once you've got that in place, let's rejig your code slightly:

```
twitter_handles = ["x", "y"]    

new_follower_ids = []
handles = []

for user in twitter_handles:
    current_user_followers = []
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=user).pages():
        current_user_followers.extend(page)

    new_follower_ids.extend(current_user_followers)
    handles.extend([user for _ in current_user_followers])

new_followers_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Handles": handles,
    "Follower_ID": new_follower_ids})
```

By keeping track of the followers for the current user within the for loop, we only need to extend the `handles` list once at the end, once we have obtained all of the new followers. As we know how many followers this user has, we can append `user` to `handles` once for each of these followers.

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much, I managed to solved it with the below code. But super appreciate your help